# Generate and compare random numbers(in a game)

Tags: javascript

**I'm stuck on this part of my code, I want to generate a random number and compare it to the number who selected the player and depending on the result give a message  **

[this is a picture of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGK9S.png)

```
let butons=document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
let result=document.getElementById('result');
let eleccionPc=document.getElementById('elP');
let eleccionPlayer=document.getElementById('elPlayer');

butons.forEach((button)=>{

  button.addEventListener('click',()=>{

eleccionPc.textContent=Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1;

       if(button.textContent==='1' < eleccionPc.textContent) {

          eleccionPlayer.textContent='1';

          result.textContent='You are Loser';
         
        } 
        else if (button.textContent==='3' > eleccionPc.textContent) {

           eleccionPlayer.textContent='3';
          result.textContent='You win MotherFucker';
        } 
        /*else if (button.textContent=="2" > eleccionPc.textContent ){
        }*/

      })
})
```

PD:I still don't know how to make a decent publication

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Could you put your code in your question body instead of the image?

Comment: You should provide a working snippet of your code, this means HTML, JS and optionally CSS. That way we can provide a full solution to your problem. Also, I suggest checking https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the if statement, you need to use && in the if statement

`if(button.textContent === '1' && button.textContent < eleccionPc.textContent)`

`else if (button.textContent === '3' && button.textContent > eleccionPc.textContent)`

This will solve the problem, If you have any question just ask me

Comment: I saw the game picture, it is very nice, keep working

Comment: && mean AND, in your if statement you have two condition and if condition one is true and condition two is true you need to continue, so here we use && which means AND, all the conditions should be true to continue.

Comment: || mean OR, If you want that if one of you condition should be true and doesn't matter if the second condition is false you can put || instead of &&, || mean If one of you condition is true just continue,

Comment: || is the oppossite of &&, if you have any question just ask me

Comment: thank you my friend, your contribution helped me a lot!

Comment: You are welcome, If you have any question just comment.

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't make any sense:

```
button.textContent==='1' < eleccionPc.textContent
```

the first half of the statement returns with "true" or "false" and then tries to see if that is less than a number?

Maybe you mean this?

```
button.textContent < eleccionPc.textContent
```

Comment: but maybe when I press the example button one generates another and that's what I don't understand *I'm quite new to the language*.